# SQL query to find the same week da last year

Tags: sql

I am new using SQL and I need to compare current year sales with the same weekday last year.

In the image below for example 06/01/2001 was on a Tuesday so I need to retrieve the same weekday last year with was on 05/01/2020 "Tuesday"

Thanks in advance

[Data with columns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lbfAA.jpg)

Comment: What is your DBMS? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? ... Date operations vary greatly from one DBMS to another.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/errors when asking a question.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551) And `Current_year` is a weird name for a date column.

Answer (score 1):

If you have data every day, then you can use `lag()`.  The same weekday last year would be 52 weeks ago (at least that is a reasonable definition).  So, using `lag()`:

```
select t.*, lag(total_sales, 52*7) over (order by current_year)
from t;
```

Comment: This is a very simple and clever solution.